# Use WatiN in windows Form to Automate Clicking and Writing in Internet Explorer C#

Tags: c#, watin

Internet Explorer is open and it is showing a webpage. We know there a drop down and a textbox and a button are exist in this page.

I need to select an item from drop down, writing a text in textBox and clicking on that button.

How Can I do these using WatiN by pressing on a button in windows form, I currently add its related libraries and I have add WatiN.Core in using section, but it seems it is not working with windows forms.

Comment: What exactly is not working? The following works for me in a button click event in a windows forms app             
    WatiN.Core.IE browser = WatiN.Core.Browser.AttachTo<WatiN.Core.IE>(WatiN.Core.Find.ByTitle("Google"));
    browser.GoTo("http://bing.com");

Comment: What error messages are you getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very small example but not sure what you mean by "not working" (does it throw an exception, are you able to start the program, when you click the button it fails, you need to be more precise on this).

```
using(var ie = new IE){
   ie.GoTo("http://www.yourwebpage.com");
   TextField entry = ie.TextField(Find.ById("myEntryBox"));
   Button btn = ie.Button(Find.ById("submit"));
   SelectList menu = ie.SelectList(Find.ById("selectList"));

   entry.Value ="Hello world");
   menu.SelectByValue("2");
   btn.Click();
}
```

if you are having other problems, please, let us know.